How to solve yarn.lock deleted in HEAD and modified in parent conflict?
I tried git revert, and have deleted yarn lock.
git revert --continue
[task/6.1/APIT-7-docusaurus3 41f44ce10d4] Revert "fix docusaurus broken link and code block rendering"
 5 files changed, 7 insertions(+), 13476 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 yarn.lock
CONFLICT (modify/delete): yarn.lock deleted in HEAD and modified in parent of 6c1a7031939 (added backslash to changelog,emulatedtimetravel,upgrade minor version).  Version parent of 6c1a7031939 (added backslash to changelog,emulatedtimetravel,upgrade minor version) of yarn.lock left in tree.

I have unmerged paths
Unmerged paths:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." as appropriate to mark resolution)
    deleted by us:   yarn.lock

what should I try now?

Solve conflicts or git revert --abort
